# optimal solution to sort contours of image by their areas using which OpenCV 3 and python 3

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, image-processing

What is the best (optimal) solution to sort contours of within an image using OpenCV 3 and Python 3?
I try this. Is it the best solution?

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image , cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = list(map(lambda c : cv2.contourArea(c), contours))
contoursWithAreas = zip(contours, areas)
sortedContoursWithArea = sorted(contoursWithAreas, key=lambda s : s[1])
sortedContours ,sortedAreas = zip(*sortedContoursWithArea)
```

finally we have sorted Contours by areas in `sortedContours` variable.

Answer (score 2):

As we all know, the contours is a list of `np.ndarray`. So we cann't avoid using numpy. Then why not use `np.argsort()`?

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
areas = np.array([cv2.contourArea(cnt) for cnt in cnts])
idxs  = areas.argsort()
cnts2 = [cnts[i] for i in idxs]
```

Comment: Is `np.argsort()` better than python sort function? Is there any comparison between those on the net?

Comment: You can make a comparation by yourself

Comment: You are right. But I want to know more about this comparison. Here is `stackoverflow` and I think with myself someone write the reason of this fact or show me a link that contains the knowledge about the `sorted` and `argsort`. Any way you are right but this isn't answer of my question. So I don't mark it as answer.

Comment: I just give a choice, and think it is more `simple or so` than your code. I'm not `Google`,I do not know everything, while  learn by `trial and error`.